# How to exlude top links from Zoom FPC cache in magento

Tags: magento, caching, zooming, browser-cache

In my home page, There is link of customer Login. After Login, text converts to Hi {username}. But after installing Zoom FPC, it does not work. The text remains "Login". How to exclude caching the text "Login"?

Comment: you probably can use placeholder ... it is better if you address this question on magento.stack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zoom extension is supported only on magento version 1.6 and lower versions. Insure that you are using this extension on magento version 1.6 or lower. It may be a reason.